# xamarin forms shell slow switching between heavy pages

Tags: performance, xamarin.forms

I have an app which uses the shell app format to switch between three equal pages through a tabbar at the bottom, plus a number of less relevant pages accessed through sidebar.
The issue is that the pages have some rather heavy mapviews with a lot of elements on them. The way the view elements on pages clear and redraw, the switching can be a little sluggish. Even seeing a page delay one second is not optimal and sometimes it may be up to five. At initial start, this can be dealt with in a form of "splash screen", but while navigating, it is not good.

I could simply make all three pages exist on the same contentpage and switch by hiding or showing the relevant mapviews, which I tried and it is with zero delay, but before doing that for real, I wonder if there is a built in fix for this using the shell and multiple different contentpages. Can hardly be the only one with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to optimize your code to improve loading efficiency.
We couldn't see the detail of your code, but we usually take the following measures to ensure that the process is more efficient:

1.[Choose the correct layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/dotnet/maui/deployment/performance#choose-the-correct-layout)

A layout that's capable of displaying multiple children, but that only has a single child, is wasteful. In addition, don't attempt to reproduce the appearance of a specific layout by using combinations of other layouts, as this results in unnecessary layout calculations being performed.

2.[Optimize image resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/dotnet/maui/deployment/performance#optimize-image-resources)

It is wasteful to decode a high resolution image in memory when it will be scaled down to a smaller size for display. Instead, reduce the CPU usage and memory footprint by creating versions of stored images that are close to the predicted display sizes. For example, an image displayed in a list view should most likely be a lower resolution than an image displayed at full-screen.

3.[Reduce the visual tree size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/dotnet/maui/deployment/performance#reduce-the-visual-tree-size)

Reducing the number of elements on a page will make the page render faster. There are two main techniques for achieving this. The first is to hide elements that aren't visible. The second technique is to remove unnecessary elements.

4.[Reduce the application resource dictionary size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/dotnet/maui/deployment/performance#reduce-the-application-resource-dictionary-size)

Any resources that are used throughout the app should be stored in the app's resource dictionary to avoid duplication. This will help to reduce the amount of XAML that has to be parsed throughout the app.

For more information, you can check document: [Improve app performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/dotnet/maui/deployment/performance) .

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately it is simply a matter of the mapview resetting in a way that takes observable time, when it is heavily populated with data. I "solved" it in my project now by having my few pages that stay live all the time, and just switch visibility, which is instant. Likely uses a bit more memory, but that I can afford, while the delay, I cannot.

Comment: If we switch between multiple pages, the controls of each page will be reloaded, which will inevitably affect the loading efficiency of the page. Therefore, when loading pages with heavy tasks, we generally use the effect of adding loading, such as `ActivityIndicator`. And your current approach is a smart one.